# Calculate in Python

Tags: python, math, calculation

is there are way to write this more comfortable in python?

```
quote_e[i] = [i, (1 * o +
                              2 * p +
                              3 * q +
                              4 * r +
                              5 * s +
                              6 * t +
                              7 * u +
                              8 * v +
                              9 * w +
                              10 * x +
                              11 * y +
                              12 * z) / 78]
```

The variables are from a list that was created before.

```
o = ema_12[i - 12][1]
            p = ema_12[i - 11][1]
            q = ema_12[i - 10][1]
            r = ema_12[i - 9][1]
            s = ema_12[i - 8][1]
            t = ema_12[i - 7][1]
            u = ema_12[i - 6][1]
            v = ema_12[i - 5][1]
            w = ema_12[i - 4][1]
            x = ema_12[i - 3][1]
            y = ema_12[i - 2][1]
            z = ema_12[i - 1][1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Daniel

Comment: Could you please explain more specifically what you mean by "more comfortable"?

Comment: What are all these variables? Where do they come from? We don't know, we can't help. Just a guess: maybe you should use a list rather than all of there unrelated variables?

Comment: Hi kingkupps. Sure. I meant that I think, that there could be a way to write it shorter. More efficient. Something like ```letters (uprising) * numbers (uprising)```. I hope that describes it better.

Comment: Hi, Thierry. The variables are from a list. ```o = ema_12[i - 12][1]
           p = ema_12[i - 11][1]
           q = ema_12[i - 10][1]
           r = ema_12[i - 9][1]
           s = ema_12[i - 8][1]
            t = ema_12[i - 7][1]
            u = ema_12[i - 6][1]
            v = ema_12[i - 5][1]
            w = ema_12[i - 4][1]
            x = ema_12[i - 3][1]
            y = ema_12[i - 2][1]
            z = ema_12[i - 1][1]```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant information - as you can see, code in comments is pretty unreadable...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille done.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_list =[ ema_12[i-j][1] for j in range(12,0,-1) ]

quote_e[i]=[i,(np.arange(1,13)*var_list)/78]
```

This creates your list of variable o to z.Here muliplication will be element-wise

I hope this is what you required

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for.